# Unable to access inner class in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef EXPENSE_H
#define EXPENSE_H

// includes
#include <string>

#define string std::string
#define ostream std::ostream
#define istream std::istream

namespace ExpenseManager{
   class Expense{
   private:
      class Inner{
         int sum;
         string date;
      };
      Inner *i;
   public:
      Expense(int sum);
      ~Expense();

      // Setters
      void setSum(int sum);
      void setDate();

      // Getters
      int getSum();
      string getDate();
      string toString() const;
      friend class Inner;
   };
}
#undef string
#undef istream
#undef ostream
#endif
```

Here is my implementation file:

```
// for switching assertions off
#define NDEBUG

// for debuging output
#define DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PREFIX "--> "

// header includes
#include "Expense.h"
#include "Time.hpp"

// includes
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

// error checking includes
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace ExpenseManager{
   using namespace std;
   class Expense::Inner{
      friend class Expese;
   };

   Expense::Expense(int sum){
#ifdef DEBUG
      clog << DEBUG_PREFIX "Constructor (1 arg) called!" << endl;
#endif
      setSum(sum);
      assert(sum >= 0);  // assure that setter "setSum" works
      i = new Expense::Inner();
   }
   Expense::~Expense(){
#ifdef DEBUG
      clog << DEBUG_PREFIX "Destructor called!" << endl;
#endif
      delete i;
   }

   // Setters
   void Expense::setSum(int sum = 0){
#ifdef DEBUG
      clog << DEBUG_PREFIX "setSum(" << sum << ") called!" << endl;
#endif
      if (sum > 0){
         i->sum = sum;
      }
      else {
         // error, throw exception
#ifdef DEBUG
         clog << DEBUG_PREFIX "invalid argument: " << sum << endl;
#endif
         throw invalid_argument("Sum must be positive!");
      }
      setDate();
   }
   void Expense::setDate(){
#ifdef DEBUG
      clog << DEBUG_PREFIX "setDate() called!" << endl;
#endif
      i->date = currentDate();  // currentDate function is in Source.hpp file
      assert(date != "");  // assure that setter works
   }

   // Getters
   int Expense::getSum(){
      return i->sum;
   }
   string Expense::getDate(){
      return i->date;
   }
   string Expense::toString() const{
      stringstream ss;
      ss << i->sum << endl;
      return ss.str();
   }
}
```

The problem is that i am unbale to reach in implementation file variables sum and date (a.k.a variables which are in inner class). I have created pointer to inner function and declared that I am trying to get information from inner class (`i->date`, `i->sum`) but this does not help. I a missing something. Maybe you can spot the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use pastebins here. Reduce your code to a minmal example that exhibits the problem and post the code here directly.

Comment: A couple of months ago, when i posted my code directly to a website, i was almost screamed at that there are tools like pastebins, in which I should put my code, because not only it saves space in here, but also it is easier for the eyes. So that is what I am doing. Say at least a couple of reasons why it is such a bad idea to use something like pastebin? It is not malware. All I can think of is advantages, rather then disadvantages of using it.

Comment: It's how this site works. Most people here sneak a peek while at work, so they probably don't want to surf around the net just for viewing code. Also, by creating a minimal example, you most often already find the problem.

Comment: "Most people here sneak a peek while at work": I never thought about such a scenario... Anyway, in the future I will try to shrink my code as much as possible and paste in here rather then in pastebin. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: A big reason to post code here is that it does not rely on external sources! The same is true of answers (Links are *good*, but at least having a relevant *excerpt* is *best*).  What happens when your "pastie.org" is down or blocked? Then someone reading the question later has no idea what it was about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misplaced the `friend`, you need to put it in `Inner` class.

```
  class Inner{
     int sum;
     string date;
     friend class Expense;
  };
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was the problem. But now I have another one. Maybe you can give it a look too?
Now i get an error `'class' type redefinition` at this line in implementation file `class Expense::Inner{`.

Comment: You need to do that in the .h, not in the .cpp.

Answer (score 2):

They are private, not public. External class cannot access this variables (and yes, `Expense` is `external class` in this case), your friend-declaration gives access to `Inner` to use private data of `Expense`, but not `Expense` to use private data of `Inner`, this relation is not transitive.